# MediaElement.js 利用時の検索結果に、ログが混ざる

Tags: javascript

MediaElement.js を利用しているのですが、 こちらを利用すると下記メッセージがGoogleの検索結果に反映されてしまいます。

```
Initializing... stage: 500x375 file: [動画パス] autoplay: false 
                preload: none isvideo: true smoothing: false 
                timerrate: 250 displayState: true 
                ExternalInterface.available: true ExternalInterface.objectID
```

こちらの解決方法について教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**

以下、利用しているコードになります。

```js
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    defaultVideoWidth: 320,
    defaultVideoHeight: 240,
    startVolume: 0,
    pauseOtherPlayers: true,
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
```

**追記2**
MediaElement.js内のflashを読み込んでいる箇所が原因のようでした。

Answer (score 1):

MediaElement.js のデバッグオプションが有効になっています。 [options](http://mediaelementjs.com/#api) に以下を追加し、デバッグオプションを無効としてください。

```
enablePluginDebug: false,
```

なぜ、どこで、有効になったのかは、質問内容からは不明です。ソース中の他の場所に、問題になる記述があるのかもしれません。ソース中に出現する "`debug`" の単語を洗ってみてください。